# Lazarus, can't get DB Update working. How can I preview whats being submitted?

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, pascal, lazarus

Hi I have a form setup using TMySQL51Connection, TSQLTransaction & TSQLQuery modules, it retrieves info from the DB without issue but I'm having problems with updates.

The DB is pretty large so I'm starting with just the 1st couple of rows, once they're working I'll extend the query.

My TSQLQuery.UpdateSQL is as follows

```
UPDATE table SET
ContactFirst = :ContactFirst,
ContactSur = :ContactSur
WHERE AccountID = :AccountID
```

Then I have a button in my form, the onCLick event contains:

```
begin
    accSelect.Edit;
    accSelect.Post;
    accSelect.ApplyUpdates;
    dbTransaction.CommitRetaining;
    sqlbl1.Caption := accSelect.UpdateSQL;
end;
```

Clicking the buttons does precisely nothing with the DB, it generates no error messages, just updates the caption on sqlbl1. Is there anyway to preview what Lazarus is sending to the DB with values included so I can track down whats going wrong?

I tried adding a logging event to the SQLConnection but couldn't work out how to get it generating logs.

Comment: Do you know how to 'Step Into' and 'Step Over' code in your IDE? Does your IDE support Watches? I know in Delphi you can step through your code one line at a time and just hover your mouse over a variable to see its current value (in Debug mode that is). I think you'll need to post more code if you're expecting us to locate bugs or incomplete coding for a particular expected functionality.

Comment: Do you assign values to the Parameters (eg. ParamByName ('ContactFirst') .Value := SomeVariant)? Perhaps you need to call an  Update or Exec method on the TSQLQuery in between the Edit and the Post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, the `Edit`, `Post` and `ApplyUpdates` methods are used in conjunction with a `TClientDataSet`. In that case you would simply assign new values to the fields in the CDS (**after** navigating to the record you want to Edit) then Post those changes (no need for an Update SQL statement). Something like this...

```
MyCDS.Edit;
MyCDS.FieldByName('ContactFirst').Value := sContactFirstName;
MyCDS.FieldByName('ContactSur').Value := sContactSurname;
MyCDS.Post;
MyCDS.ApplyUpdates;
```

Alternatively, you could use a Query component, write the UPDATE SQL into the SQL property, and use `ExecSQL` or whatever method has been implemented for that component (there are many database access components that each have their own idiosyncrasies)

Here's some code off the top of my head. Please excuse me but I'm not familiar with Lazarus specifics - it's basically Delphi code.

```
MySQLQuery.SQL.Clear;
MySQLQuery.SQL := 'UPDATE MyTable 
                   SET    ContactFirst = :ContactFirst,
                          ContactSur = :ContactSur
                   WHERE AccountID = :AccountID';
MySQLQuery.Params.ParamByName('ContactFirst').Value := sContactFirstName;
MySQLQuery.Params.ParamByName('ContactSur').Value := sContactSurname;
MySQLQuery.Params.ParamByName('AccountID').Value := iAccountID;
try
  MySQLQuery.ExecSQL;
  ShowMessage('Update succeeded');
except on e: Exception do
  ShowMessage(e.Message);
end;
```

So it might be that you've ended up using half of both methods and neither of them completely.

Comment: That was good enough for me, I used the 2nd suggestion, works perfectly :D

Comment: Future FPC versions will have TSqlStatement that is slightly better optimized for this kind of stuff.